# SharePoint List export and import

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, custom-list, export

I want to export a SharePoint 2010 List and import it into another site. This list has 2500+ items in it and a Workflow attached to it. Workflow gets triggered on adding a new item.

If the List is exported, will the Workflow come along with the list when imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not bring the workflows along with it. this is an extract from a nice Blog

> Site export/import is almost useless for custom solutions that contain
>   custom workflows, event receivers, custom web, and item properties,
>   custom event receivers, version history etc. It has problems even if
>   it’s used for simple sites that use only SharePoint out of the box
>   functionality if it has listed with workflows and versioning enabled.

Guys tested 3 different options and said above. read more here.
http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/site-collection-backup-restore-vs-site-export-import-with-focus